# Python balance brackets checker

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, brackets

I'm trying to create a function that checks for balance brackets, according to the class I created.
But I keep getting False all the time.
I would really appreciate if you could show me where I was wrong and explain me the solution to my mistake.

```
    class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []
        self.__top = 0

    def is_Empty(self):
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return "Stack Empty!"
        else:
            return f"Your stack is not Empty!\nThe current stack is {self.my_stack()}"

    def __str__(self):
        """Print current stack"""
        return self.my_stack()

    def push(self, item):
        """Push item in stack."""
        self.__items.append(item)
        self.__top += 1

    def pop(self):
        """Remove top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        self.__top -= 1
        return self.__items.pop()

    def top(self):
        """Return top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return self.__items[-1]

    def my_stack(self):
        """Show the current stack"""
        if not self.__items:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return f"The current stack is {self.__items}"


def check_balance(test):
    """
    Return True if brackets are balanced, False otherwise.
    """
    oppositeBracket = {']': '[', ')': '(', '}': '{'}
    lefts = Stack()
    for char in test:
        if char in '[({':
            lefts.push(char)
        if char in '])}':
            if lefts.is_Empty():
                return False
            else:
                if lefts.top() != oppositeBracket[char]:
                    return False
            lefts.pop()
    if not lefts:
        return True
    return False
```

for example:

```
print(check_balance("(10+10)"))
```

And I get

```
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating is_Empty as returning a boolean, but it doesn't. It returns a string in either case.  (and such is always "True" in a boolean sense)

UnitTest:

```
l = Stack()
l.push('1')
assert not l.is_Empty()
```

This assert should not fail, but does.

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 small bugs in your code:

- `isEmpty` method returns always `True` since you return non empty string.
- Your final check for empty stack (`if not lefts`) is always `True` as well since `lefts` is equal to your stack object and it even if it's empty, it won't be logical `False`.

The code should be:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__items = []
        self.__top = 0

    def is_Empty(self):
        return self.__top <= 0


    def __str__(self):
        """Print current stack"""
        return self.my_stack()

    def push(self, item):
        """Push item in stack."""
        self.__items.append(item)
        self.__top += 1

    def pop(self):
        """Remove top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        self.__top -= 1
        return self.__items.pop()

    def top(self):
        """Return top of the stack."""
        if self.__top <= 0:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return self.__items[-1]

    def my_stack(self):
        """Show the current stack"""
        if not self.__items:
            return self.is_Empty()
        else:
            return f"The current stack is {self.__items}"

def check_balance(test):
    """
    Return True if brackets are balanced, False otherwise.
    """
    oppositeBracket = {']': '[', ')': '(', '}': '{'}
    lefts = Stack()
    for char in test:
        if char in '[({':
            lefts.push(char)
        elif char in '])}':
            if lefts.is_Empty():
                return False
            else:
                if lefts.top() != oppositeBracket[char]:
                    return False
            lefts.pop()
    return lefts.is_Empty()
```